# Large amount of 404 Not Found errors due to unknown reason

Tags: url, internationalization, seo, web-crawler, persian

My website worked correctly until last week, when suddenly lots of "not found" errors appeared. The error message is visible but I cannot find the reason. The errors stated that the pages that are unable to be found are linked from sitemap.xml, however prior to the errors appearing Google was able to crawl through the website correctly. Here is an example:

Real link in sitemap (This is the old link that is still functional):

`https://rohamweb.com/webdesign/174-طراحی-حرفه-ای-سایت-در-تهران.html`

What the search console is actually pointing to:

`https://rohamweb.com/webdesign/174-`

Apparently the crawlers cannot read content after `-`, likely due to the different language. I have never encountered this issue until last week, in which perviously was functional.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the actual link :`https://rohamweb.com/webdesign/174-طراحی-حرفه-ای-سایت-در-تهران.html`, you are doing it wrong and it should be **URL encoded** before sending it to the response: 
`https://rohamweb.com/webdesign/174-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%81%D9%87-%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86.html`
In this case, all of the available engines are able to follow it.